# Oracle Error "inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got LONG"

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I'm trying to run the following query to find views containing a given keyword:

```
select  *
from    ALL_VIEWS
where   OWNER = 'SALESDBA'
        and TEXT like '%rownum%';
```

I'm getting the following error message:

```
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got LONG
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 4 Column: 13
```

if I just select from ALL_VIEWS than I see the query (TEXT) in the TEXT field.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What's the column OWNER's data type? What's the column TEXT's data type?

Comment: what's the type of owner?

Comment: The problem is with the TEXT field - If I remove and and TEXT like '%rownum% from the query than it works - and as mentioned I see the query - which means it's a text field - on which I would like to filter.

Answer (score 17):

Your problem is that TEXT is of type LONG - although Oracle deprecated this type a long, long time ago, they're still using it in their own views :-(

To convert a LONG to a (searchable) CLOB, you can use the `TO_LOB()` function (see [Oracle documentation for TO_LOB()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14249/adlob_long_lob.htm).

Unfortunately, this doesn't work for simple `SELECT` statements. You'll have to create an intermediary table:

```
create table search_all_views as 
select  av.owner, av.view_name, to_lob(text) as text_clob
from    ALL_VIEWS av;
```

Then, you can search using that table:

```
select * 
from search_all_views
where text_clob like '%rownum%';
```

Comment: @psaraj12 Please re-read the docs carefully: "You cannot use the TO_LOB function to convert a LONG column to a LOB column in the subquery of a CREATE TABLE ... AS SELECT statement *if you are creating an index-organized table*" (before posting my answer, I tried it on 11gR2, and it worked as expected).

Comment: Yes, i also tried and works, but why it's not possible do this on the fly, i mean in a simple sql without creating a table. i really don't understand this issue.

Comment: @Aramillo I agree it's a brain-dead limitation - if you cannot use the CTAS workaround, then I'd recommend you contact Oracle support.

Answer (score 5):

You could use TEXT_VC as the column to check criteria against.  For example:

```
select  *
from    ALL_VIEWS
where   OWNER = 'SALESDBA'
        and TEXT_VC like '%rownum%';
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: This is a *valid* update for 12g, but it should be noted, that the data type is VARCHAR2(4000) so the text can be truncated.